# Size of integral in line

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, integral

I don’t know what is happening. Currently, when I type `$\int_a^b f$`, the integral sign is always big, as if I’m typing `$$\int_a^b f$$`. I’m using `\textstyle` to correct this, but I wanted not to have to type this, and that the size of integral was text style normally.

Does some one know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: what you describe does not happen by default so must be due to code you have not shown. Please always show a complete small document that shows the problem

Comment: do you have `\everymath{\displaystyle}` ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) There is no way for us to tell you how to fix this without knowing how you broke it `:-)`. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle YES, that was the problem... I just copied the preamble of another file and didn't realize it was there... thanks, I was getting crazy with this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you have `\everymath{\displaystyle}` somewhere. You sometimes see this recommended on the internet, but it's almost always wrong, it destroys inline math setting, as you see.